# Showing only part of the custom meta in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress code that displays a check list for each wordpress user. The code works fine and I am able to get it to display on a page.

```
<?php

        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'todo_listing', 'posts_per_page' => 3,'order'=>'ASC' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        $_meta_val_arr=array(10=>"All Item",0=>"Cat0",
            1=> "cat1",
            2=>"cat2",
            );

?>      

 <?php
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>
        <li class="todo" id="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" itemage="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_todotime',true)?>"><a href="javascript:;"
        <?php if($all_meta_for_user[get_the_ID()][0]){              
?>
        class="strike"
        <?php
         }
        ?>
        >           
        <?php if($all_meta_for_user[get_the_ID()][0]){?>
            <span class="check_box cb"></span>
            <?php }else{?>
        <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>
        <?php }?>   
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>           
        <?php
        endwhile;
        ?>
```

I just want to show those items with with Class ="strike" which is saved as meta  [1012] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) where 1012 is the todo id.